# Saving TimePicker data in a sqlite database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, timepicker

Ok - So I'm really lost at this point...

I have an xml layout where a user can input several settings. My goal is to be able to save these settings and retrieve them at a later date - which I've done successfully up until this point. I have sqlite database which stores several values including the currentHour from the timepicker as well as another xml layout which outputs the settings saved in the database.

Currently - the timePicker only saves the currentHour to the database and then to the string I'm using to display it in the view_country XML file.

What I'd like to do is display the entire time - not just the currentHour (ex. currentHour : currentMinute in order to display the full time 4:00AM) as a string I can use to display the time in another xml layout.

P.S.

I really need a straightforward answer on how this can be done (just assume I know nothing) I've been trying to accomplish this for several days and I still need assistance getting the currentMinute displayed next to my currentHour.

I've made several attempts at this however at this time I feel its best to revert back to my last known working state (I've been getting force close issues when attempting different methods of concatenating the two fields) and ask for help. (I know it can't be TOO hard to store and display a time value from a TimePicker - especially for some of you more skilled StackOverflow ninjas)

add_country.xml (where the TimePicker buttons are)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">

   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:padding="5dp">

      <EditText android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
         android:hint="@string/name_hint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/capEdit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:imeOptions="actionNext" 
         android:hint="@string/cap_hint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10MB" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Unlimited Data" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bandwidth Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="10kbs" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WiFi Time Limit"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/codeEdit"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines="1"
        android:hint="@string/code_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />




      <Button android:id="@+id/saveBtn" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:text="@string/save_btn"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

AddEditCountry.java  (Java file for the layout containing the TimePicker buttons)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);



          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));    
             String time = extras.getInt("time");
             String[] parts = time.split(":");
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(parts[0]);
             timeEt.setCurrentMinute(parts[1]);
          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                              + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                         capEt.getText().toString(),
                         timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                             + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                         codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
           }
}
```

DatbaseConnector.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseConnector {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

       public void open() throws SQLException 
       {
          //open database in reading/writing mode
          database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       } 

       public void close() 
       {
          if (database != null)
             database.close();
       }       

       public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time) 
               {
                  ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
                  newCon.put("name", name);
                  newCon.put("cap", cap);
                  newCon.put("time", time);
                  newCon.put("code", code);

                  open();
                  database.insert("country", null, newCon);
                  close();
               }


               public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code, String time) 
               {
                  ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
                  editCon.put("name", name);
                  editCon.put("cap", cap);
                  editCon.put("time", time);
                  editCon.put("code", code);

                  open();
                  database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }


               public Cursor getAllContacts() 
               {
                  return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                     null, null, null, null, "name");
               }

               public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
               {
                  return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
               }

               public void deleteContact(long id) 
               {
                  open(); 
                  database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }
}
```

view_country.xml (where the currentHour is displayed at the moment - but needs to display the currentHour and currentMinute together as one string I can display as the time)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">
<TableRow>         
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/nameText" 
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/capText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>

  <TableRow>       
  <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Time Limit"/>                    
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/codeText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="Linked Users"/>         
 <TextView 
android:id="@+id/codeText"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>         
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow>         
 <TextView 
    style="@style/StyleLabel"
    android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>         
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/timeEdit"
    style="@style/StyleText"/>  

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
03-25 12:50:45.175: D/Activity(10602): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-25 12:50:45.265: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(10602): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-25 12:50:45.276: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca42000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:57
03-25 12:50:45.276: E/(10602): Can't open file for reading
03-25 12:50:45.276: E/(10602): Can't open file for reading
03-25 12:50:45.316: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d12f000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:61
03-25 12:50:45.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10602): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-25 12:50:45.326: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10602): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-25 12:50:47.248: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca42000 size:614400
03-25 12:50:47.248: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d12f000 size:614400
03-25 12:50:47.288: D/Activity(10602): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-25 12:50:47.318: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(10602): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-25 12:50:47.318: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5cd67000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:58
03-25 12:50:47.388: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d05f000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:63
03-25 12:50:47.388: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10602): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-25 12:50:48.549: D/memalloc(10602): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d12f000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the minutes by keeping one column in the database and one string. Then you must split the `time` string, when setting the `TimePicker`

```
String time = extras.getString("time");
String[] parts = time.split(":");
timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
timeEt.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
```

and concat it, when inserting or updating

```
dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                              + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
```

Or keep a separate `hour` and `minute`. This means extending the database schema and `DatabaseConnector` to cope for an additional parameter, but avoids splitting the string, when you need the parts.

Comment: I updated my source code above... and my logcat -its force closing and I get the following errors after adding your suggested code : (

Comment: The method setCurrentMinute(Integer) in the type TimePicker is not applicable for the arguments (String) AddEditCountry.java line 48 Java Problem
The method updateContact(long, String, String, String, String) in the type DatabaseConnector is not applicable for the arguments (long, String, String, String) AddEditCountry.java line 105 Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String AddEditCountry.java line 45 Java Problem
The method setCurrentHour(Integer) in the type TimePicker is not applicable for the arguments (String) AddEditCountry.java line 47 Java Problem

Comment: @NoobNinja I needed to use `getString` and added the needed conversion `Integer.valueOf`. Please see updated answer.